# Percentage Outlier Detection

Tags: php, algorithm, math, outliers

Hi im trying to make a simple script that will find outliers in datasets:

The class looks like this:

```
namespace App\Classes;

class PercentageOutlier {
    private int $percentage;
    private array $dataset;
    private ?string $key;

    private array $normalitiesDataset = [];
    private array $outlierDataset = [];

    // todo - make som error handling for providing multidimensional array without a key
    // count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)
    public function __construct(int $percentage, array $dataset, ?string $key = null) {
        $this->percentage = $percentage;
        $this->dataset = $dataset;
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    // Method to detect outlier tickers
    public function detectOutliers(): void
    {
        $average = $this->key === null
             ? array_sum($this->dataset) / count($this->dataset)
             : array_sum(array_column($this->dataset, $this->key)) / count($this->dataset);


        foreach ($this->dataset as $key => $data) {
            $rate = $this->key === null ? $data : $data[$this->key];

            // Calculate the percentage difference between the current datapoint and the average datapoint
            $percentageDifference = abs(($rate - $average) / $average * 100);

            if ($percentageDifference > $this->percentage) {
                $this->outlierDataset[$key] = $data;
            } else {
                $this->normalitiesDataset[$key] = $data;
            }
        }
    }

    public function hasOutliers(): bool
    {
        return $this->countOutliers() > 0;
    }

    public function countOutliers(): int
    {
        return count($this->outlierDataset);
    }

    public function hasNormalities(): bool
    {
        return $this->countNormalities() > 0;
    }

    public function countNormalities(): int
    {
        return count($this->normalitiesDataset);
    }

    public function getOutliers(): array
    {
        return $this->outlierDataset;
    }

    public function getNormalities(): array
    {
        return $this->normalitiesDataset;
    }
}
```

The script works very well for a dataset looking like this:

```
$dataset = [
    0 => 1303.38028120000000000000,
    1 => 1303.57226533330000000000,
    2 => 1303.47627326660000000000,
    3 => 1363.60716566840000000000,
    4 => 1781.57864604160000000000,
    5 => 1314.34978900860000000000,
];
```

It will return a outliers array looking like this which is correct:

```
array:1 [
  4 => 1781.5786460416
]
```

However if i provide a slightly modified dataset which has 2 outliers at index 3 and 4:

```
$dataset = [
    0 => 1303.38028120000000000000,
    1 => 1303.57226533330000000000,
    2 => 1303.47627326660000000000,
    3 => 1763.60716566840000000000,
    4 => 1781.57864604160000000000,
    5 => 1314.34978900860000000000,
];
```

It will return the whole array as outliers because the average is now too far away from all datapoints

Im calling the script with a percentage value of 10 like so:

```
$outlier = new PercentageOutlier(10, $dataset);
$outlier->detectOutliers();

$normalities = $outlier->getNormalities();
$outliers = $outlier->getOutliers();

echo 'we have normalities: '.$outlier->countNormalities();
echo 'we have outliers: '.$outlier->countOutliers();

dump($normalities);
dd($outliers);
```

Can someone help me in the right direction? I've been looking at stuff like IQR/LOF algorithms but i don't seem to be math wiz enough to make something that come close to working :)

Comment: What's the expected output? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with the best odds calculates the absolute differences of the value from the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) and deletes all values whose differences are greater than a certain value epsilon. Calculating the median is easy:

```
 /*
  * @return: Median from array data, false if error
  * @param : Array of data
  */
  public static function median(array $data)
  {
    if(($count = count($data)) < 1) return false;
    sort($data, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $mid = (int)($count/2);
    if($count % 2) return $data[$mid];
    return  ($data[$mid] + $data[$mid-1])/2;
  }
```

Determining a good value for the epsilon is more difficult. This often still works for artificial datasets. Example for the first dataset:

```
$median = 1308.961027171;
$eps = 100;
$outliers = [];
foreach($dataset as $key => $value){
  if(abs($value - $median) > $eps) {
     $outliers[$key] = $value;
  }
}
//$outliers: array(1) { [4]=> float(1781.5786460416) }
```

The problems arise when the algorithm is to be applied to real series of measurements.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time to answer my question, regarding the $epsilon value, is there some guidance for a good eps value? like maybe a cheatsheet for a good eps on different thousand ranges?

Like a standard for
these ranges:
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000

So If the median is lets say 100, the eps would be like 10, and median at 1000 would be 150 maybe? or something similar, or maybe a percentage of the median?

Comment: For these examples here you can just take $eps = $median/10 to get an $eps regardless of the size of the values.